# Getting a lot of Mariadb log-error message with WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE

Tags: mariadb, galera

I have setup Mariadb Galera cluster with 3 Node and recently after checking the
mysql error-log file I got surprised to see (string like below) is repeating.

I am confused why it is repeating so many time the same [Note] and
should I be concern for this.

2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE
2018-06-24 12:57:34 140400686594816 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE

Kindly help.

Comment: Resolved the issue by removing wsrep_debug=OFF;